# Is it possible to do the Rails project (not tracked in any source control system) deployment with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano

I have a Rails project developed locally and don't want to put into any source control system like github or bitbucket etc. I can use SSH or FTP etc to copy the Rails project into my VPS. Is it possible to use Capistrano to do the deployment in my case? I check the Capistrano documentation and it says Capistrano supports git, mercurial and svn. I'm not sure if it can be used without any source control system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Capistrano 2.x could do it, although it didn't always work very well. I don't think Capistrano 3.x can.

In [an issue on the Capistrano github project](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/722), where someone else asked this question, the Capistrano author says:

> [Capistrano is]  a tool to launch code out of SCM into a deployment environment.

Even if you could get Capistrano (or another similar tool) to deploy without source control, deploying something to production that isn't in source control is a bad idea.